# Does the NEC allow a 14ga branch on a 12ga circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Is it within the NEC to wire ceiling light fixtures with 14ga NM from a switch wired with 12ga NM, where the power originates at the switch and the ceiling fixture is a branch?

The breaker protecting the circuit is 20 amp.

Comment: If the switch is a 15 ampere switch duty (SWD) circuit breaker, there would be no problem.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it within the NEC to wire ceiling light fixtures with 14ga NM from
>   a switch wired with 12ga NM, where the power originates at the switch
>   and the ceiling fixture is a branch?
>
> The breaker protecting the circuit is 20 amp.

Absolutely not. If the branch circuit is 20A then ALL the wiring on the circuit must be at least #12cu.

Yes, there are convoluted tap rules but they would not apply in this installation and IMO are not even worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

No, Using 14ga is against code. See `Table 210.24` in the NEC:

[image]

And if we visit 240.4 which is a reference for fixture wires, we have:

> **(D) Small Conductors**. Unless specifically permitted in
>   240.4(E) or (G), the overcurrent protection shall not exceed
>   that required by (D)(1) through (D)(7) after any correction
>   factors for ambient temperature and number of conductors
>   have been applied.
>
> ...
>
> **(3) 14 AWG Copper**. 15 amperes
>
> **(4) 12 AWG Aluminum and Copper-Clad Aluminum**. 15 amperes
>
> **(5) 12 AWG Copper**. 20 amperes

Best to use 12Ga NM.

Answer (score -1):

I had an interesting experience when I built my previous house back in 1996.  There was a very large voltage drop in the master bedroom, which I noticed when vacuuming one day.  I looked up the NEC code, and there was only a "recommendation" that the voltage drop be no more than 5% to the end of a circuit. I was getting closer to 15%.  Turns out the apprentice had wired the house up and down the walls, instead of through the studs; about tripling the wire run needed.  I finally settled with the owner of the electrical company to run 12 gauge as far as he could up that circuit, which did help quite a bit, and was the only optimal solution since the house was already completed.